# VBA to merge ppt slides into master ppt slide

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

Hello Stackoverflow experts. Please help if there's a VBA script that can merge ppt files.
I have 11 slides, 1 is master slide and 10 are individual report slides.
I want a VBA code to merge all individual report slides into my master slide.
All slides are in the same folder. Thanks a lot for anything you can help.

Have tried search but cannot find any solutions online.

Comment: How can slides be "in the same folder"? A slide is part of a Presentation.

Comment: All slides are in the same folder. Yes it is part...a slide is the title page of the presentation...thanks

Comment: By "slides in the same folder" Rhett probably means "single-slide presentations in the same folder".  So for all intents and purposes a presentation=a slide in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go.

```
Sub InsertAllSlides()
'  Insert all slides from all presentations in the same folder as this one
'  INTO this one; do not attempt to insert THIS file into itself, though.

    Dim vArray() As String
    Dim x As Long

    ' Change "*.PPT" to "*.PPTX" or whatever if necessary:
    EnumerateFiles ActivePresentation.Path & "\", "*.pptx", vArray

    With ActivePresentation
        For x = 1 To UBound(vArray)
            If Len(vArray(x)) > 0 Then
                .Slides.InsertFromFile vArray(x), .Slides.Count
            End If
        Next
    End With

End Sub

Sub EnumerateFiles(ByVal sDirectory As String, _
    ByVal sFileSpec As String, _
    ByRef vArray As Variant)
    ' collect all files matching the file spec into vArray, an array of strings

    Dim sTemp As String
    ReDim vArray(1 To 1)

    sTemp = Dir$(sDirectory & sFileSpec)
    Do While Len(sTemp) > 0
        ' NOT the "mother ship" ... current presentation
        If sTemp <> ActivePresentation.Name Then
            ReDim Preserve vArray(1 To UBound(vArray) + 1)
            vArray(UBound(vArray)) = sDirectory & sTemp
        End If
        sTemp = Dir$
    Loop

End Sub
```